# Make a Number Expression

Tags: code-challenge, stack

Few years ago, an esoteric programming language named [아희(Aheui)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Aheui) was created. Well, actually you don't need to know about this language or Korean characters.

Aheui uses stacks and a queue, but this time we use **one stack** and ignore other stacks and queue. You can **push a number** between 2 and 9 into a stack. You can do **arithmetic operations** by popping two numbers and pushing result. And you can **duplicate** a top number.

So, when I need a big number in Aheui, making a number was not an easy work. Push, push, multiply, duplicate, push, multiply, push, add…. It takes too much time and sometimes waste of bytes. I need a shortest expressions.

### Summary

Your task is to write a function or a program which takes a number `n (0 <= n <= 1000000)` and returns concatenation of tokens.

Tokens are basically a [postfix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). Tokens are consisted of

- Number between 2 and 9, which means "push number into stack"
- `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, which means "pop two numbers from stack, do arithmetic operation, push the result into stack". All calculations are in integer.
- `>`, which means "duplicate a top number"

Tokens will be concatenated with empty string, so `5 5 +` will be `55+`.

After calculations, `n` must be on the top of the stack.

#### Sample input and output

```
INPUT = 0
OUTPUT = 22-
(or 33-, 44-, whatever)

INPUT = 1
OUTPUT = 22/
(or 32-, 33/, whatever)

INPUT = 5
OUTPUT = 5
(We don't need calculations, just push)

INPUT = 64
OUTPUT = 88*
(or 8>*)

INPUT = 1337
OUTPUT = 75*2+>*48*-
(This may not be a shortest solution)
```

### Scoring

[This is a list of test cases](http://pastebin.com/ASmgRY1t). Test cases are seperated by a new line character. You may write a test script which converts those bunch of numbers to string of tokens, or you can do it by your hand.

Let

- `S` = size of complete function or program
- `O` = length of converted strings
- `I` = size of test cases (In this case, `I = 526`)

Then your score will be `S * (O / I)`. Sizes are in bytes.

`S` includes function declarations, `#include`s, `import`s, whatever. Test script is not counted.

### Scoring example

Let `S` is `150`.

#### Sample Test cases

```
0
1
5
64
1337
```

#### Sample Output

```
22-22/588*75*2+>*48*-
```

In this case, `I = 9`, and `O = 21`. So your score is `150 * (21 / 9) = 350`.

### Rules

- [Standard "loopholes"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/9275) are forbidden.
- Lowest score wins.
- If there is a tie, smaller code size wins.
- Winner will be selected after three weeks (2014-08-04).

---

I wrote a [validator in Node.js](https://gist.github.com/Snack-X/61cb01e800b0b4ff475e). Put `input.txt` and `output.txt` in same directory, and run `node validator.js`.

And I found [two-year-old similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5271/generate-number-in-reverse-polish-notation). But scoring is different (this question includes code size in score), and this question can't use 1. So I hope it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Clarification needed. 1.The requested number must be on top of stack? What if the stack is not empty after popping the result? 2.Division is integer or floating point?

Comment: @edc65 1. Yes. It must be on the top of the stack. 2. Integer, floor. `53/ = 1`, not `2`.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, Score = 1663.46768

```javascript
function X($){S=Math.sqrt;function J(A){return A.join("")}function M(A,B){return A.length<B.length?A:B}function D(q){var w="",e,r,t,y;for(e=9;e>1;e--){r=~~(q/e);t=r*e-q;if(t==0)y=J([G(r),e,"*"]);else y=J([G(r),e,"*",G(-t),"+"]);if(w=="")w=y;w=M(w,y)}return w}function Q(a){var s=~~S(a),d=a-s*s,f=J([G(s),">*",G(d),"+"]),g;s=Math.ceil(S(a));d=s*s-a;g=J([G(s),">*",G(d),"-"]);return M(f,g)}function G(z){var x,c,v,b,n,m;if(z==0)return"22-";if(z==1)return"22/";if(z>1&&z<10)return""+z;if(z>9&&z<19){x=~~(z/2);c=z-x;return J([x,c,"+"])}for(v=9;v>1;v--){b=~~(z/v);if(b>1&&b<10&&b*v==z)return J([v,b,"*"])}n=S(z);if(~~n==n)return J([G(n),">*"]);return M(D(z),Q(z))}return G($)}
```

This is my attempt for my question, and [this is output](http://pastebin.com/UJ5r7VZs). Code size is 671, and output size is 1304. Score is 1663.46768 (rounded up to 5 decimal places).

Comment: If you can transform your functions (or some of them) to functional form, meaning that you can transform them such that a function like `function F(a){return <lots of code>}` becomes possible, you can use the ECMAscript 6 syntax `F=(a)=><lots of code>`. Furthermore, you have `if(z==0)return"22-";if(z==1)return"22/";`. I think you can compress that to `if(z<2)return["22-","22/"][z];`. (If `z` can be negative, add a `&&z>=0`.)

Comment: +1 Great job! Golfed a little more and rewrited for EcmaScript 6 your code size is 406. `X=$=>(S=Math.sqrt,M=(A,B)=>A.length<B.length?A:B,D=(q,w="",e,r,t,y)=>{for(e=9;e>1;e--)r=~~(q/e),t=q-r*e,y=t?G(r)+e+"*"+G(t)+"+":G(r)+e+"*",w=M(w||y,y);return w},
Q=(a,s=~~S(a))=>M(G(s)+">*"+G(a-s*s)+"+",G(++s)+">*"+G(s*s-a)+"-"),
G=(z,v,b)=>{if(z<18)return z<2?"22"+"-/"[z]:z<10?z:"8"+(z-8)+"+";for(v=9;v>1;v--)if((b=~~(z/v))>1&b<10&b*v==z)return""+v+b+"*";return ~~(v=S(z))-v?M(D(z),Q(z)):G(v)+">*"},G($))`